# JavaScript, transform object into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an object:

```
var obj = {
    "Mike": 24,
    "Peter": 23,
    "Simon": 33,
    "Tom": 12,
    "Frank": 31
};
```

I want to create an array that holds the values of the object. The keys (key names) can be disregarded:

```
[24, 23, 33, 12, 31]
```

**The order of the values is NOT important!**

One solution (obviously) would be do have a function that takes the values and puts them into an array:

```
var arr = valuesToArray(obj);
```

I will accept such a function as the answer. However, I would be more pleased if there would be an API function (ECMAScript, jQuery, browser-specific, ...) that could do this. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use **Object.values** it will return array.

```
Object.values(obj) // [24, 23, 33, 12, 31]
```

Answer (score 46):

The obvious way would be to do a for-in loop, as [@quixoto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607991/javascript-transform-object-into-array/4608021#4608021) suggests, but just for the record, and since you are looking for a *built-in* way, you could pair the new ECMAScript 5 methods [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), available on [latest browsers](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/):

```
function valuesToArray(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { return obj[key]; });
}
```

**UPDATE**: ES2017 introduced the [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) method, which does exactly what you want.

Additionally, ES2017 adds another often useful method, [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries). This method returns an array of *key-value pairs*.

```js
const obj = {
    "Mike": 24,
    "Peter": 23,
    "Simon": 33,
    "Tom": 12,
    "Frank": 31
};

const values = Object.values(obj);
const entries = Object.entries(obj);
console.log('values:', values);
console.log('entries:', entries);
```

Comment: Nice :) This is probably as small as it can possibly get.

Comment: Or even shorter in ES6:
`Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key])`

Answer (score 6):

There's no built-in way to do this anywhere. The following does what you suggest, and may be "shortened" into more clever functional-programming versions depending on your library, but they'll all have the same efficiency.

```
function valuesToArray(obj) {
    var result = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
       if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
           result.push(obj[key]);
       }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

With jQuery you could use the each function:

```
var obj = {
    "Mike": 24,
    "Peter": 23,
    "Simon": 33,
    "Tom": 12,
    "Frank": 31
}

myArray=new Array();
$.each(obj, function(key, value) { 
  myArray.push(value);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Posting this strictly for fun. Save your downvotes. I'm not recommending it actually be used. **;o)**

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/WGpXX/

```
var arr = eval( '[' +
    JSON.stringify(obj)
    .slice(1,-1)
    .replace(/"[^"]+":/g,'')
    + ']');
```

*Technically* works in this simple case.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for! ... just kidding :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the Underscore lib try:

```
function valuesToArray(o) {
    return _.pairs(o);
}

var obj = {
    "Mike": 24,
    "Peter": 23
    //...
    },
    result = valuesToArray(obj);
```

Then the result is [ ["Mike", 24], ["Peter", 23] ];

More detail on the pairs method here: http://underscorejs.org/#pairs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var obj = {     "Mike": 24,     "Peter": 23,     "Simon": 33,     "Tom": 12,     "Frank": 31 } ;
    var arr = []
    for(var a in obj)
    {
        var val = obj[a];
        arr.push(val);
    }
alert(arr.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some libraries have something to do this (such as prototype's "values" function), but they're really just wrappers around a function that loops over and returns the values of the object.

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/object/values

Answer (score 0):

Using [bob.js](http://www.bobjs.com) this can be done pretty simply:

```
function valuesToArray(obj) {
    return bob.collections.extensions.toArray.call(obj);
}
```