# How can I retrieve the object into an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I'm currently practicing some basic problem in js and fairly new to any of these languages. I want to retrieve the value and name of the property into an array "temp" from the object "second" if the another obj "third" has the same property value. 
I can do it, when the property name is already defined, but how can I do the same if I don't know the actual property name. May be using Object.keys()

My code is something like this:

```
      function where(second, third) {
  var arr = [];
  var temp=[];
  for(var i in second)
    {

      if(third.hasOwnProperty('last')){
        if(second[i].last===third.last){
          arr=second[i];
          temp.push(arr);
        }
      }
      if(third.hasOwnProperty('first')){
        if(second[i].first===third.first){
          arr=second[i];
          temp.push(arr);
        }
      }

    }
  return temp;
}

where([{ first: 'Ram', last: 'Ktm' }, { first: 'Sam', last: null }, { first: 'Tybalt', last: 'Capulet' }], { last: 'Capulet' });
```

The resulting array is : `[{ 'first': 'Tybalt', 'last': 'Capulet' }]`

How can I retrieve the same result even if I don't know the actual property name. For instance the name here first and last might be food, and uses which is unknown. 
I've already gone with the following threads here.

[[2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607991/javascript-transform-object-into-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

[[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607991/javascript-transform-object-into-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: Whats  `for(var i in collection)`, where's the `collection`

Comment: @fuyushimoya, just corrected that it meant to be for(var i in second).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function where(second, third) {
    var temp = [];
    var k = Object.keys(third)[0]; // expecting only one element!
    second.forEach(function (obj) {
        if (obj[k] === third[k]) {
            temp.push(obj);
        }
    });
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: `obj` is a parameter of the callback function.

Answer (score 1):

I think the getOwnPropertyName is what you're looking for.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames({a:1,2:"b",c:"a"}).sort() // returns Array [ "2", "a", "c" ]
```

I'll expand on my initial answer

```
var temp = [];

var myobj = [{cat:"Felix",dog:"Milo",bird:"Monkey",3:"pets"}, 
         {cat:"Wiskers",dog:"yapper",bird:"tweeter",1:"human"}];

var myobj2 = {cat:"Harry",dog:"Fuzz",1:"human"};

var objKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myobj); //will have key "1" that matches below

objKeys.forEach(function(key) {
    if(myobj2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        temp.push(myobj2[key]) // will push "human" to temp array
    }
})
```

Comment: that's looks pretty and short but I'm not sure, will try to use this.

Comment: whoops. I actually forgot something. Helping people at 5am may not be a good thing.. Need to loop myobj to get each object's keys :<

Comment: I think Nina Scholz's answer is probably the best.

Comment: Thanks! I must appreciate your support and I do.

Answer (score 0):

```
function where(second, third) {
  var tmp = [];
  var length = second.length;

  var i, k, test;
  // Go through second's each item to see that...
  for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    test = second[i];
    // For all key in third that belongs to third (not inherited or else)
    for (k in third) {
      // Check has own property.
      if (!third.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        continue;
      }
      // If second[i] don't have key `k` in second or second[i][k]'s value is 
      // not equal to third[k], then don't put it into tmp, start to check next.
      if (!third.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        break;
      } else if (test[k] !== third[k]) {
        break;
      }
      tmp.push(test);
    }
  }
  return tmp;
}
```

Comment: @fuyshimoya , thank you! I couldn't even vote up. You perfectly filtered the value of the "third".

Comment: I edited, for you use the `hasOwnProperty`, which you may concern if your object is extended or created by some extended prototypes.

Comment: What would be the approach, If I wish to use Object.keys(). Assume I'm very newbie.

Comment: @fuyushimoya, ya `hasOwnProperty` seems not a good idea, actually I didn't know how else I could go. So I just thought using it should be in very lower level to understand, actually your first answer was more understandable but this too is fairly simple. Thank you for clarifying me.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think `hasOwnProperty ` is not a good idea, it's good or not depends on how you create the object you want to test, anyway, if you accept Nina Scholz' s answer, notify her that her answer will only check first key of the object, so if there's more than 1 key in `third`, outcome might not be what you want.

Comment: Like `where([{ first: 'Ram', last: 'Ktm' }, { first: 'Sam', last: null }, { first: 'Tybalt', last: 'Capulet' }], { first: 'Sam', last: 'Capulet' });` will output `[{first: 'Sam', last: null}]`, which I believe you may expect an empty array?

Comment: @fuyushimoya, if you change the specifications, like not null/undefined results, or third is an array, then the answer may vary.

Comment: @NinaScholz of course, so I just think it should be better if you edit your code to accept multiple keys situation, as the op didn't mention there's only 1 key in the third object. Anyway, it just a suggestion, not a request or something like that.